# Google Maps InfoWindow ImageView

Tags: android, google-maps, infowindow

I'm trying load a dynamic image in my InfoWindow in Google Maps v2. I'm having a fun race condition between loading the image from memory and the getInfoContents returning the view to be displayed.  Even if the image is in memory, in a Bitmap, it might not finish drawing by the time the view is returned. I've tried a lot of solutions online, but none have been 100%.

Below is my current code. I override the getInfoContents method of GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter.

Anyone have an idea how to deal with this?

```
    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(final Marker marker) {
        final View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.template_map_info_window, null);

        final ImageView vehicleImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.infowindow_image);
        vehicleImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

        return view;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can gain some idea form [here](http://androidfreakers.blogspot.com/2013/08/display-custom-info-window-with.html).

Also, you can consider use the library [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso),

Consider implements `Callback` which your image load finish, it will be display.

Sample code:

```
@Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView)myContentsView.findViewById(R.id.imgView);
            if (not_first_time_showing_info_window) {
                Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(YOU_IMAGE).into(imageView);
            } else { // if it's the first time, load the image with the callback set
                not_first_time_showing_info_window=true;
                Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(YOU_IMAGE).into(imageView,new InfoWindowRefresher(marker));
            }

            return myContentsView;
        }

private class InfoWindowRefresher implements Callback {
        private Marker markerToRefresh;

        private InfoWindowRefresher(Marker markerToRefresh) {
            this.markerToRefresh = markerToRefresh;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            markerToRefresh.showInfoWindow();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError() {}
    }
```